# JavaScript: How to check if an event isset?

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I'm using a function to add an `onClick` event to a `<div>`, like:

```
onClick='function(param)
```

How can I check now if this event is set at all? `div.onClick` doesn't do it's job.

EDIT: I tried now this:

```
if (typeof div.onClick === 'function')
```

...and this:

```
if (!typeof div.onClick === 'function')
```

and both cases are false.

Comment: You should be adding event handlers [the correct way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener). Or, better yet, just have a [JavaScript library](http://jquery.com/) do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (typeof el.onclick == "function") {
  // ...
}
```

Also, make sure your script is placed at the bottom of the page. You can't select elements otherwise.

Comment: typeof does not work properly in my case, I think. Because this case somehow happens, it's alwasy false, even if there is a function...

Comment: Ahem ... he he he :S sorry, was my mistake ^^ thanks for the answer ;)

Comment: @negative - Would you read the question, please? Who was talking about jQuery here? Go back and download the `jQuery.learnToRead` plugin.

Comment: @Florian - you may accept the answer, if your problem was solved.

Comment: @galambalazs, uhm, trouble answering questions without points awarded? I get it.

Comment: @negative - Accepting an answer is for everybody else to see if a problem was solved.

Comment: @galambalazs actually my comment was to your previous reply.